# Creating a button with a Bitmap image wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am using wxPython on Python 2.7.
I would like some help with creating a button with bitmap images.

I am using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7f0a7xbWHI,
and I followed the codes and typed

```
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Frame aka window',size=(300,200))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)

        pic=wx.Image("back.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.button=wx.BitmapButton(panel, -1, pic, pos=(10,10))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.doMe, self.button)
        self.button.SetDefault()

    def doMe(self, event):
        self.Destroy
```

to create a button with an image. I got an error stating Invalid Image.
I saved the bitmap image in a folder that has .py file I am working with.
I feel like I am saving the image in the wrong place?
Thank you in advance.

The error I received

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\FrameWindow.py", line 81, in <module>
    frame=bucky(parent=None,id=-1)
  File "C:\Python27\FrameWindow.py", line 17, in __init__
     pic=wx.Image("back.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 708, in _Image_ConvertToBitmap
    bmp = wx.Bitmap(self, depth)
wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "image.IsOk()" failed at ..\..\src  \msw\bitmap.cpp(922) in wxBitmap::CreateFromImage(): invalid image
```

Comment: It's very helpful to include the error you received so that way other people can Google the error message and find it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'm a noob here. I just added the error codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY` rather than `wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP` it takes the guessing out of whether it really is a BMP or not
or use `wx.Bitmap()` directly.

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,'Frame aka window',size=(300,200))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        #
        # Use wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY rather than wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP
        #
        #pic=wx.Image("Discord.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        #
        # or use wx.Bitmap()
        pic = wx.Bitmap("Discord.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        #
        self.button=wx.BitmapButton(panel, -1, pic, pos=(10,10))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.doMe, self.button)
        self.Show()

    def doMe(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
      app = wx.App()
      frame = MainFrame()
      app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

In principle you should name your image/s with a full pathname. If you have many images, then have an image directory and `join` that directory name to your image names as you use them, which again gives you a full path (/home/images/back_button.bmp)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your method, and now it says "wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "strcmp(setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL), "C") == 0" failed at ..\..\src\common\intl.cpp(1579) in wxLocale::GetInfo(): You probably called setlocale() directly instead of using wxLocale and now there is a mismatch between C/C++ and Windows locale.
Things are going to break, please only change locale by creating wxLocale objects to avoid this!" What do I do in this case?

Comment: No Idea. My simple code above runs happily on Linux Mint 18.3, with no reference to locale, as you can see from the code. Did the error occur running the code above,as is, or did you apply the changes to your code? If the latter try running just the code above as a standalone program (changing the name of the image, obviously)

Comment: Yes, I tried running your code as is with my image. Is there any specific place I need to have my images saved to use on wxPython??

Comment: Also, my code seems to be working when I don't run the module on IDLE, but left-click the .py file name in the folder. The error message shows when I "run module" on IDLE, but when I left-click the file name, it has my picture and everything seems to be working.

Comment: I know nothing of IDLE. I code from the command line. In principle you should name your image/s with a full pathname. If you have many images, then have an image directory and `join` that directory name to your image names as you use them, which again gives you a full path (/home/images/back_button.bmp)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by adding

```
"locale = wx.Locale(wx.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)"
```

under

```
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
```

now I do not get the error message, and it runs as it should.
The error code I received for this problem was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python27\panel test.py", line 21, in <module>
      frame = MainFrame()
   File "C:\Python27\panel test.py", line 11, in __init__
      pic = wx.Bitmap("back.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
 wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "strcmp(setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL), "C") == 0" failed at ..\..\src\common\intl.cpp(1579) in wxLocale::GetInfo(): You probably called setlocale() directly instead of using wxLocale and now there is a mismatch between C/C++ and Windows locale.
 Things are going to break, please only change locale by creating wxLocale objects to avoid this!
```

The error given by my primary question was solved by the codes given by Rolf by Saxony.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking the tick mark beside it. You can mark an answer as Useful or Not Useful by clicking the Up/Down arrows beside it, respectively. Or you can accept your own answer (but you don't get any points for that). It's your call.